# Scrapy not installed correctly on mac?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I have tried to install `Scrapy` on mac 10.8.2. Here's what I did:

In terminal, I ran the command from with myuser directory:

```
pip install --user scrapy
```

I got the following message in Terminal:

```
Successfully installed scrapy
Cleaning up...
```

Next I do the following from the same myuser dir:

```
scrapy shell http://example.com
```

Here's the error I am getting:

```
-bash: scrapy: command not found
```

I believe this is a path issue, scrapy has been installed in /Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages. How do I get scrapy to run?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`--user` option is used when you want to install a package into the local user's `$HOME`, e.g. on Mac it should be `$HOME/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages`.

`scrapy` executable could be found at `$HOME/Library/Python/2.7/bin/scrapy`. So, you should edit your `.bash_login` file and modify `PATH` env variable:

```
PATH="$HOME/Library/Python/2.7/bin/:$PATH"
```

Or, just reinstall scrapy without `--user` flag.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I uninstalled scrapy, and reinstalled using sudo. Everything looks good now.

Comment: If you're using Python 3.7 on OSx you need to append `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin` to your path